# Exclusion-Inclusion principle.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this problem in discrete maths (combinatorics) which nags me.

We have a computer system, where a password is of length of at least 3 signs and at most 100 signs.

The premitted signs to use are a-z , A-Z, 0-9.

A password must contain at least one letter from a-z, at least one letter from A-Z and at least one digit from 0-9.

One day, there was a glitch in the process of checking the password which caused that there wasn't relevance for the order of the signs in the password nor to the repetition of signs.

E.g, the system didn't differentiate between the next passwords:
BA1Aa11, aAB1, 1AAAABBBaa
since in those three passwords appear the same signs.

How many different passwords were possible in the day of the glitch?
Where passwords that are the same, are passwords which the system didn't differentiate between them.

I understand that I need to use here inclusion-exclusion, but I am a bit rusty with using it here.

Can you help me?

Obviously for a password of 3 signs we have 26*26*10 options for password, but to start calculating for the rest of the passwords is a little bit too much, is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to choose a non-empty subset $S_1$ from $\{a,\ldots,z\}$, a non-empty subset $S_2$ from $\{A,\ldots,Z\}$ and a non-empty subset $S_3$ from $\{0,\ldots,9\}$. Each combination of those subsets will give a unique (for that day, as order and repetition are not counted) different and valid password.

So I get $(2^{26}-1)(2^{26}-1)(2^{10}-1)$ as the answer.

Comment: Where does the restriction on the number of signs comes in? I mean a password should be between 3 to 100 signs. I don't see this come into play in your counting, right?

Comment: That's right. A longer one is equivalent to a shorter one. The 100 upper limit guarantees that all combinations will give rise to a valid password

Comment: Right, because we can only use 62 signs in overall.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Indeed. Adding more doesn't help. We can always reduce to an equivalent password of at most this maximal length.

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^{26}-1$ options for capitals, $2^{26}-1$ options for lower-case and $2^{10}-1$ options for numbers.  Multiply them together.